# .htaccess Redirect dynamic URLS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**Old URL**: 1. http://www.example.com/hotel-list/something

**New URL**: 2. http://www.example.com/something/hotel-list"hotel-list" is actually hotel-list.phpOld URLs in Google search are giving 404. How can we redirect properly?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show your existing .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try either:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/hotel-list/(.*)$ /$1/hotel-list
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^hotel-list/(.*)$ /$1/hotel-list [L,R=301]
```